# setInterval function not running using JavaScript ES6

Tags: javascript, setinterval

This is driving me potty

```
const video = document.querySelector('.video'); // grab the element
const randomInt = () => Math.random().toFixed(2); // get random int from 0 - 1 and round to two decimal points
const runTimer = () => setInterval(randomInt, 100); // function to call randomInt every 100ms
video.style.opacity = runTimer(); // set the opacity at random every 100ms
```

I didn't know if this was a problem with ES6 and using implicit or explicit returns. FWIW I have also tried using trad Javascript, like

`runTimer() {...}`

Or `function runTimer() {...}` (as well as for the other functions, none seem to work).

This must be something simple I am missing right?

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/9ta6svpz/)

```js
const video = document.querySelector('.video'); // grab the element
const randomInt = () => Math.random().toFixed(2); // get random int from 0 - 1 and round to two decimal points
const runTimer = () => setInterval(randomInt, 100); // function to call randomInt every 100ms
video.style.opacity = runTimer(); // set the opacity at random every 100ms
```

```css
video {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video class="video" poster="https://64.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_qsflcrfAoC1z0l4vz_smart1.jpg" preload="none" muted="" data-crt-video="" crossorigin="anonymous" tabindex="-1" loop controls>
    <source src="https://va.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_qsflcrfAoC1z0l4vz_480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: `setInterval()` completely ignores any value returned from the callback function. You'll have to do the opacity update *inside* the callback.

Comment: Note that your code is not written in "ECMA5". The minimum level of ECMAScript (aka JavaScript) that supported arrow functions and `const` is ES2015 (aka ES6).

Comment: Your code assigns to `opacity` only *once*, and it assigns the number that `setInterval` returns, which is unrelated to your random number, but is a timer ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code sort of tries to have `runTimer` reach out and reuse the code prior to the call to it within the timer interval. Functions can't do that.

Instead, move all of the logic that you want to run for each interval callback, including the `video.style.opacity =` part, *inside* a function that you pass to `setInterval`. See `***` comments:

```
const video = document.querySelector('.video'); // grab the element
const randomInt = () => Math.random().toFixed(2); // get random int from 0 - 1 and round to two decimal points
const updateOpacity = () => video.style.opacity = randomInt(); // ***
const runTimer = () => setInterval(updateOpacity, 100); // function to call randomInt every 100ms
// *** −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
runTimer(); // set the opacity at random every 100ms
```

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. I have an appalling memory for the ECMA5 ES6 standards nonsense, maybe that's why my question was downvoted

Comment: @lharby - Who can say. :-) (FWIW, these days I don't think there's really any reason to call out specific versions.) Happy coding!